# Recurrence is null after calling /me/calendarView

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have a recurring meeting scheduled, however when making a call to `/me/calendarView` with the GraphAPI, the event `recurrence` field comes back as `null`. The event does indeed have a `seriesMasterId` returned. I have tried in graph explorer and in my code, have not found been able to get it work. I also tried using a query that looks like the following (which contains recurrence):

```
$select=subject,isOrganizer,organizer,attendees,start,end,location,recurrence,responseStatus,organizer
```

The exact request is a `GET` on `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView/?startdatetime=2018-10-05T14:25:25.049Z&enddatetime=2018-10-06T04:59:59.049Z`

I still had no luck after using this. Any suggestions as to why recurrence would be `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recurrence pattern for a series lives with the Series Master, *not* the Instances.

The fact that you're receiving a `seriesMasterId` tells us you're looking at an Instance rather than the Master. A Series Master will have a `recurrence` value but not a `seriesMaster`.

- If `recurrence == null` and `seriesMaster == null` then it is a simple **Event**
- If `recurrence != null` and `seriesMaster == null` then it is a **Series Master**
- If `recurrence == null` and `seriesMaster != null` then it is an **Instance** in a series

In order to see the recurrence pattern, you need to request the Series Master:

```
/me/events/{seriesMaster-id}
```